# Efficient real time HTML table

Tags: javascript, json, performance

I have continually updating data where html table needs to be updated. Table is relatively large with 200 rows and 15 columns.Data(JSON) is fetched through XHR request and the table should be updated only for the change in the data. Any addition, update and deletion of rows should also be taken care. What's the best framework or approach to follow. I tried angularJS and it's slow in IE8.

View(HTML table) should not be redrawn for small change in a cell. Only the changes should be updated.

Thanks

Comment: html5 websocket might help with the data transfer

Comment: 200 rows doesn't sound that huge…

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at jTable.  Pretty awesome jQuery table with AJAX support built in.

http://www.jtable.org

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/).

They provide a lot of api's to play around table and very easy to use.

Answer (score -1):

Check out this table from Codyhouse:
https://codyhouse.co/gem/schedule-template/
This is an amazingly styled timetable.

Hope this helps.